# Write Conflict on data submitted through form

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access as a front-end to my PostgreSQL database. My workflow is pretty simple:

- Create a linked table using the ODBC driver
- Build a form using form wizard for data entry

Inserting data works really well if i submit the data directly on the table or using the form. However, i can update the data that was submitted directly to the table, but i cannot update the data submitted through the form as i get a write.conflict error.

[image]

I checked many previous answers and one of the issues was to do with the timestamp precision. This helped with updating the data submitted directly on the table as it didn't work before.

Now i just need to resolve updating data that was submitted using the form. I tried using Me.Dirty as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)

    Me.Dirty = False

End Sub
```

That didn't work for me unfortunately. It really does look like something to do with the form as entering data using the table works perfectly. Is it how the form saves the data? How can i get it off editing mode? I really don't know and i tried various things.

I would really appreciate a hand on this as i have been on it for days and i can't resolve it.

Thank you.

---

Here is a simplified version of the code i used to create my table. I just have more VARCHAR and numeric columns in the table i am using.

I also created a logs table that would update if any changes are made to the main table. This logs table is populate via a trigger as shown in the code.

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT to_char(now(), 'YYMMDDHH24MI') :: INT,
    column_1 VARCHAR(50),
    column_2 VARCHAR(100),
    column_3 BOOLEAN,
    last_updated timestamp(0));
                    

CREATE TABLE logs_table
(like table_1 EXCLUDING CONSTRAINTS,
operation char(10) not null,
date_operated timestamp(0) default current_timestamp
);


create function logs_function()
    returns trigger as $$
    BEGIN
        insert into logs_table (id, column_1, column_2, column_3, last_updated, operation)

        values (old.id, old.column_1, old.column_2, old.column_3, old.last_updated, TG_OP);
        
        IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
        THEN
            new.last_updated := current_timestamp;

            RETURN NEW;

        ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE'
        THEN
            RETURN OLD;

        END IF;

    end;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER logs_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON table_1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE logs_function();
```

Comment: I'm guessing it still a timestamp issue. What did you do to solve the update from table? Is there a timestamp field in the form? If so what are its properties? What does the Postgres server log show when you update from the form?

Comment: Hello @AdrianKlaver, thank you for your reply. I only have one timestamp column with a data type of timestamp(0). 

I solved the update on the table by changing the data type of the timestamp as seen. I can update as much as i want on the table, but it gives the write conflict error if the data is submitted from the form.

How can i check the Postgres server log when a write.conflict arises?

Comment: Yes but what are the properties of the form field for the timestamp value? Also the log information?

Comment: The form does not feed into the timestamp column. The timestamp column is used when an update on the form occurs. I created another table to save the previous version of the row if any updates or deletes are made on the main table via a trigger. The trigger will automatically populate the timestamp column with the value of Now().

Since the trigger is only activated when an update or delete occurs, should it cause a write.conflict?

Comment: I think it is more likely that it is changing the value under the Access transaction and Access is seeing the discrepancy  and marking it as an update by another user. Is this a `BEFORE` trigger? If so you might want to move at least the timestamp rewrite to an an `AFTER` trigger to see if that helps.

Comment: User initiates edit mode with data entry then code attempts to edit record. This is seen as two users. Edit question to show code that edits data.

Comment: One thing i am finding hard to grasp is why would the trigger be an issue when data is entered through the form, as opposed to data being entered directly into the table?

Comment: I actually disabled the function and trigger to test the form on the table alone. I am still getting the write.conflict error. This shows that it definitely has to do with the form. Any thoughts?

Comment: Give the Boolean column a default of 0 - not allow nulls. The timestamp column should also help.  Assuming that "timestamp" is in fact a row version column and has nothing to do with the actual time.